# Reading and Manipulating a Text File in Java

Tags: java, file, integer, int

I've been trying for a while now to read a single String from a .txt file, convert it to an Integer, add a new value and save it to the .txt file again.

I have been semi successful if I only write "fw.write(String.valueOf(amount));" to the file, but it just replaces the current String with a new value. I want to grab the current String in the file, convert it to an Integer and add more to the value.

I currently get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null` error, but I am converting to an Integer so I don't understand. The error points to

```
content = Integer.parseInt(line);

//and

int tax = loadTax() + amount;
```

Here are my two methods

```
public void saveTax(int amount) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    int tax = loadTax() + amount;
    try {
        File file = new File("data/taxPot.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());

        fw.write(String.valueOf(tax));
        fw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public int loadTax() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/taxPot.txt"));

        String line = br.readLine();
        int content = 0;

        while (line != null) {
            line = br.readLine();
            content = Integer.parseInt(line);
        }
            br.close();

            return content;
    }
```

Can anyone see why it is returning null and not adding `tax + amount`?

Comment: Well, you called br.readLine() twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try swapping around:

```
if (line == null)
  return content;
do {
  content = Integer.parseInt(line);
  line = br.readLine();
} while (line != null);
```

This will fix the issue where line might be null.

Comment: Thanks to everyone that commented. This comment resulted in the expected result for me. I knew it was something simple, and a lesson learned. Thanks davecom!

Comment: No problem, @SLaks helped me quickly see what code you needed to change.

Answer (score 8):

After you read the last line from the file, `br.readLine()` will return null, which you then pass to `parseInt()`.
You can't parse `null`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. When you've been staring at something so long and re-writing it, the small things seem to not be so obvious.